# How to create a dialog like Google Map in android

Tags: android

I want to create a dialog like this:
[image: n]
Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, I haven't any idea

Comment: Dialog with different alignement can be used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_photo_dialog);

Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount = 0.7f;
lp.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
//Show the dialog
dialog.show();
```